# Run when a post-type is saved run a function in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to add_action in Wordpress such that when a post of the type 'fep_message' is saved I check for any '_fep_delete_by_' keys associated with the post_parent ID and then I delete them from the wp_post_meta table.  This is the code I built to do that but it is not working:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'undelete_thread');
function undelete_thread($post_id, $post) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ($post->post_type = 'fep_message'){
        $participants = fep_get_participants( $post->post_parent );
        foreach( $participants as $participant ) 
        {
            $query ="SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = %s and `meta_key` = '_fep_delete_by_%s'";
            $queryp = $wpdb->prepare($query, array($post->post_parent, $participant));
            if (!empty($queryp)) {
                delete_post_meta($queryp,'_fep_delete_by_' . $participant); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the proper hook to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the save_post hook in wordpress. You can find more info here

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

The code then should be changed to this:

```
add_action('save_post', 'undelete_thread');

function undelete_thread($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $post; 

    if ($post->post_type = 'fep_message'){
        $participants = fep_get_participants( $post->post_parent );
        foreach( $participants as $participant ) 
        {
            $query ="SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = %s and `meta_key` = '_fep_delete_by_%s'";
            $queryp = $wpdb->prepare($query, array($post->post_parent, $participant));
            if (!empty($queryp)) {
                delete_post_meta($queryp,'_fep_delete_by_' . $participant); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kris, you are correct, save_post works.  I simplified the function more and this is working well:

```
add_action('save_post', 'undelete_thread');
function undelete_thread($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ($post->post_type = 'fep_message'){
        $participants = fep_get_participants( $post->post_parent );
        foreach( $participants as $participant )        
        {
            delete_post_meta($post->post_parent,'_fep_delete_by_'. $participant );    
        }
    }
}
```